# How to check elements from array? Avoid overlapping of my circles and match the speed for the circle spawn behind

Tags: arrays, processing

Hi what I am trying to achieve here is not overlap the circle moving from left to right. the x coordinate is random generated, so should I check and make sure a minimum gap there so it execute draw? If so how do I do it.

Also speed is random as well, so I want to match the speed from behind to the front one(also not going backwards) and do no overtake it.

Sorry I am doing very basic coding now, so I can't use class or array for functions.

```
//declare global variables 
    int N_CARS_IN_LANE = 30;
    int MIN_GAP = 50;
    float xPed;
    float yPed;
    float dia;
    boolean isCollide=false;
    float [] xPos;
    float [] yPos;
    float [] dias;
    float [] xSpeed;
    
    void setup() {
      size(1200, 400);
      background(255);
      xPed=width/2;
      yPed=7*height/8;
      dia=height/4;
      init();
    }
    void init() {
      xPos= new float[N_CARS_IN_LANE];
      yPos= new float[N_CARS_IN_LANE];
      dias= new float [N_CARS_IN_LANE];
      xSpeed= new float [N_CARS_IN_LANE];
      for ( int i=0; i<xPos.length; i++) {
        for (int k=i+1; k< N_CARS_IN_LANE; k++) {
          xPos[i]= random(-150);
          xPos[k]=xPos[i]-k;
          yPos[i]=height/8;
          dias[i]=50;
          xSpeed[i]=random(10);
        }
      }
    }
    void  draw() {
      //reset background
      background(255);
      balls();
      moveballs();
      ballsisOffscreen();
      collideballs();
    }
    
    void balls() {
      for (int i=0; i<N_CARS_IN_LANE; i++) {   
        if (isCollide!=true) {
          fill(0, 255, 0);
          circle (xPos[i], yPos[i], dias[i]);   
    //should I put conditions here to make sure balls are separated for a MIN_GAP when draw?
        }
      }
    }
    void moveballs() {
      for (int i=0; i<N_CARS_IN_LANE; i++) {  
        //for (int k=i+1; k<N_CARS_IN_LANE; k++) {  
        xPos[i] = xPos[i] + xSpeed[i];       
      }
    }
     //check balls draw is not overlapping? and maintain a MIN_GAP
    void collideballs() {
      for (int i=0; i<N_CARS_IN_LANE; i++) {   
        for (int k=i+1; k< N_CARS_IN_LANE; k++) {    //check elements from array?
          if (isCollide&&xPos[i]!=xPos[k]) {           
            xSpeed[k]=xSpeed[i];                    // match speed from behind to from?
          }
        }
      }
    }
    boolean isCollide() {
      for (int i=0; i<N_CARS_IN_LANE; i++) {   
        for (int k=i+1; k< N_CARS_IN_LANE; k++) {
          // distance between balls
          float leftright =((xPos[i]-dias[i]/2) -(xPos[k]+dias[k]/2));  
          float rightleft=((xPos[k]-dias[k]/2)-(xPos[i]+dias[i]/2));
          if ((leftright<MIN_GAP)&&(xPos[i]!=xPos[k])&&rightleft>MIN_GAP) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    //reset ball
    void ballsisOffscreen() {
      for (int i=0; i<N_CARS_IN_LANE; i++) {   
        if (xPos[i]>width) {
          xPos[i]=-200;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: All the resources I can find is comparing on class array lists. How do I achieve without class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understud correctly what you were asking for, but I hope I did it right.

I just added the speed to the position of the ball and then checked if this moves it to close to the ball in the front of it. In that case I just set it right behind the ball in front.

But for this to work you have to know which ball is in front of the current ball.
For that you could loop through all of your balls and search for the ball whoose coordinate is closest but bigger than the current balls.

Also I think it would make your code much more readable if you used Objects for the balls. That way you also don't have to search for the next ball and it makes it easier to expand later.

Here is a version I've coded up quickly that implements the balls/cars as objects and also solves your problem with collision. I hope that helps you to fix your code [Or you just copy&paste this one ;-) ]

```java
ArrayList<Car> cars;
int carAmount = 10;
int carSize = 50;
int gab = 5;

void setup(){
  size(1200, 400);
  cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  float posLastCar = width+ carSize*2 + gab; //could also be any other big number
  if(random(100) > 97 && cars.size()< carAmount){ 
    //if there are not enought cars there is a 3% chance of a new one spaning
    cars.add(new Car(carSize, gab, 100));
  }
  for(Car car: cars){ //loops through all cars
    car.update(posLastCar);
    posLastCar = car.posX; //save pos of this car for the next
  }
  if(cars.size() > 0){
    if(cars.get(0).isAtEnd()){ //checks if first car is at the end
      cars.remove(0); //then removes it
    }
  }
}

class Car {
  float posY;
  float radius;
  float gab;
  float posX;
  float speed;
  
  Car(float radius, float gab, float posY){
    this.radius = radius;
    this.gab = gab;
    this.posY = posY;
    speed = random(3, 10); //picks random speed between 3 and 10
    // to reduce the amount of extremly slow, blocking cars
    posX = 0;
  }

  void move(float posNextCar) {
    posX += speed;
    
    if(posX + radius + gab > posNextCar){
      posX = posNextCar - radius - gab;
    }
  }
  
  void update(float posNextCar){
    move(posNextCar);
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    circle (posX, posY, radius);
  }
  
  boolean isAtEnd(){
    if (posX >= width + radius){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```